# Convert quoted list to plain list in Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell

I know how to use `read` to change `String` to `Int`, for instance using

```
 map read ["3","2","1"] :: [[Int]]
```

But i got stuck when it came to irregular lists, like

```
["3","[3,5]","[5,3]"],["4","[1,9]","[2,3]"]
```

How to convert it to `[[3,[3,5],[5,3]],[4,[1,9],[2,3]]`?

Comment: Remember, every value in Haskell has a type.  What's the type of your desired result? Think about this very carefully.

Comment: I think that would be [Int,[Int],[Int]] but I don't exactly know who to express it in code

Comment: @user3689497 That isn't a valid type in Haskell.  You can have something like `(Int, [Int], [Int])`, but lists _must_ contain elements of _a single type_.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do isn't possible in Haskell, because the value `[[3, [3, 5], [5, 4]], [4, [1, 9], [2, 3]]` has an invalid type.  There aren't even enough close brackets in there, you're one short.  What would the type of `[3, [3, 5]]` be?  `[[Int]]`?  `[Int]`?  Neither fit.

Even your example is wrong:

```
> map read ["3", "2", "1"] :: [[Int]]
[*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

Because `[3, 2, 1]` has type `[Int]`, not `[[Int]]`.  Remember, this isn't Python, lists can only contain elements of a single type.

---

Instead, if you have input like `["3", "[3,5]", "[5,3]"]`, you can parse it with something more like

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

readEither :: (Read a, Read b) => String -> Maybe (Either a b)
readEither s = case readMaybe s of
    Just x -> Just $ Left x
    Nothing -> case readMaybe s of
        Just y -> Just $ Right y
        Nothing -> Nothing
```

This can be expressed shorter, but I think this gets the point across pretty well.  You can then use it to parse your values:

```
parseMyList :: [String] -> [Maybe (Either Int [Int])]
parseMyList = map readEither
```

And use it as

```
> parseMyList ["3", "[3,5]", "[5,3"]  -- Incomplete last element!
[Just (Left 3), Just (Right [3,5]), Nothing]
```

I left an accidental typo in there so you could see that it fails gracefully as well.

---

A shorter implementation can be written using `Monoid`:

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)
import Data.Monoid

readEither :: (Read a, Read b) => String -> Maybe (Either a b)
readEither = getFirst $ mconcat $ map First [fmap Left $ readMaybe s, fmap Right $ readMaybe s]
```

Maybe someone can golf it some more.

Comment: Not interested in golfing, but `Either Int [Int]` is a strange value type for this situation.  A tree is almost surely the right thing.

Comment: @luqui not necessarily, OP never indicated that this was a nested structure. If it is a nested structure then a tree is certainly the way to go, but if it's only a choice between a single int or a list of them then a tree is overkill.

Comment: True, technically, yes.  I was sort of generalizing based on my expectation of the "smoothness" of many problems (which is of course uninformed in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Using readMaybe as bheklilr did, I thought you maybe make use of `[[Int]]` as the resulting data type.

```
> import Text.Read (readMaybe)
> map (\x->maybe [read x] id $ readMaybe x) ["3", "[3,5]", "[5,3]"] :: [[Int]]
[[3],[3,5],[5,3]]
```

If you want a flat list, you could even use `concat` on the result.